# how to pass more values for a single parameter in storedprocedure in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, tsqlt

MY text:-

```
CREATE proc usp_delete    
        @tranid int           
        as 
        begin 
    delete from customer where tranid in(@tranid)
     end
```

Note:- I want to delete records more than 1 records through this stored procedure like:- if I pass 1,2,3,4,5,6 that time all 6 records should be deleted

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Use `STRING_SPLIT` with `IN` and you are good to go.

Comment: @CoderofCode `string_split` was introduced in 2016 version... older versions must use other techniques to split strings (usually a UDF)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `table-valued parameter` for that you need to declare that

```
CREATE TYPE EntityId AS TABLE  
( Id INT )
 GO

CREATE PROCEDURE usp_delete    
    @tranid EntityId READONLY
AS 
 BEGIN 
     DELETE c
     FROM customer c
     JOIN @tranid t ON t.Id=c.tranid 
 END
```

For Executing with TVP declare a  varible of type and pass it to the stored procedure

```
 DECLARE @entityId EntityId 

 INSERT INTO @entityId 
 VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4),(5)

 EXEC usp_delete @entityId
```

Comment: can you explain how to use this

Comment: You can use exec command for that declare a pararmeter of type EntityId and pass it the stored procedure

Comment: when I executing your code it shows error  like           Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure usp_delete, Line 5 [Batch Start Line 10]
Incorrect syntax near 'c'.

Comment: @ganesh i didn't understand your question .can please elaborate your requirement

Comment: @ Sanal Sunny     without inserting directly delete more than 1 records from table is it possible

Comment: @ganesh for that, If you can specify the reason for deleting this much record then we can write a procedure for that logic

Comment: lot of data is there sometimes I have to delete  10 or 100or 500 records from the table based on id. based on requirement we have to do

Comment: @ganesh what is the criteria for choosing id

Comment: id is the primary key

Comment: @ganseh not that what is the reason to choose these id for delete.try to lmplement that logic in your sp . eg : delete records that is created 30 days before

Answer (score 0):

In later version of SQL Server you can use STRING_SPLIT to convert a delimited list into individual values and then join to your table using CROSS APPLY.

```
CREATE PROC usp_delete @tranid VARCHAR(MAX) AS
BEGIN
    DELETE c
    FROM   customer c
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(@tranid, ',')
    WHERE c.tranid = value
END
GO
EXEC usp_delete '2,3,4'
```

In older version you can write your own table-valued function to convert a delimited string into a result set.

```
CREATE function [dbo].[delimited_string_to_table] (
     @delimiter char(1)
   , @string    text
)
returns @table table (
     seqnbr  int           not null
   , string  varchar(255)  not null
)
as
begin

   declare @pos      int
   declare @textpos  int
   declare @chunklen smallint
   declare @tmpstr   varchar(8000)
   declare @leftover varchar(8000)
   declare @tmpval   varchar(8000)
   declare @seq int = 1

   set @textpos = 1
   set @leftover = ''

   while @textpos <= datalength(@string)
   begin

      set @chunklen = 8000 - datalength(@leftover) / 2
      set @tmpstr = @leftover + substring(@string, @textpos, @chunklen)
      set @textpos = @textpos + @chunklen

      set @pos = charindex(@delimiter, @tmpstr)

      while @pos > 0
      begin
         set @tmpval = ltrim(rtrim(left(@tmpstr, @pos - 1)))
         insert @table (seqnbr, string) values(@seq, @tmpval)
         set @tmpstr = substring(@tmpstr, @pos + 1, len(@tmpstr))
         set @pos = charindex(@delimiter, @tmpstr)
         set @seq = @seq + 1
      end

      set @leftover = @tmpstr

   end

   if len(rtrim(ltrim(@leftover))) != 0
      insert @table(seqnbr, string) values (@seq, ltrim(rtrim(@leftover)))

   return

end
GO
```

Which would change the example to look like this:

```
CREATE PROC usp_delete @tranid VARCHAR(MAX) AS
BEGIN
    DELETE c
    FROM   customer c
    JOIN   dbo.delimited_string_to_table(',', @tranid)
           ON c.tranid = string
END
GO
```

Comment: Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Procedure usp_delete1, Line 3 [Batch Start Line 87]
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '
52' to data type int.

Comment: exec usp_delete1  '51,
52,
53,
54,
55,
56,
57,
58,
59,
60,
61,
62,
63,
64'

Comment: exec usp_delete1 is sp name